# Azure Signalr +Azure function + wpf client - how to have a wpf client application using azure funtion and self hosted Azure SignalR App

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-signalr

when searching for azure signalR connected through functions almost all result in Asp clients. is it possible to have wpf client(4.7) or wpf core app as client?

Comment: Yes you can use the .NET Standard client to connect to it. Follow the same instructions as for JavaScript. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#configuring-a-client-connection

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use WPF as a client for that, you can take a look at main.xaml sample file:

```
﻿using System; 
using System.Net.Http; 
using System.Windows; 
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client; 

namespace WPFClient 
{    
    /// <summary> 
    /// SignalR client hosted in a WPF application. The client 
    /// lets the user pick a user name, connect to the server asynchronously 
    /// to not block the UI thread, and send chat messages to all connected  
    /// clients whether they are hosted in WinForms, WPF, or a web application. 
    /// For simplicity, MVVM will not be used for this sample. 
    /// </summary> 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window 
    { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// This name is simply added to sent messages to identify the user; this  
        /// sample does not include authentication. 
        /// </summary> 
        public String UserName { get; set; } 
        public IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; } 
        const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080/signalr"; 
        public HubConnection Connection { get; set; } 

        public MainWindow() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

        private void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, TextBoxMessage.Text); 
            TextBoxMessage.Text = String.Empty; 
            TextBoxMessage.Focus(); 
        } 

        /// <summary> 
        /// Creates and connects the hub connection and hub proxy. This method 
        /// is called asynchronously from SignInButton_Click. 
        /// </summary> 
        private async void ConnectAsync() 
        { 
            Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI); 
            Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed; 
            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub"); 
            //Handle incoming event from server: use Invoke to write to console from SignalR's thread 
            HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) => 
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}\r", name, message)) 
                ) 
            ); 
            try 
            { 
                await Connection.Start(); 
            } 
            catch (HttpRequestException) 
            { 
                StatusText.Content = "Unable to connect to server: Start server before connecting clients."; 
                //No connection: Don't enable Send button or show chat UI 
                return; 
            } 

            //Show chat UI; hide login UI 
            SignInPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
            ChatPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
            ButtonSend.IsEnabled = true; 
            TextBoxMessage.Focus(); 
            RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText("Connected to server at " + ServerURI + "\r"); 
        } 

        /// <summary> 
        /// If the server is stopped, the connection will time out after 30 seconds (default), and the  
        /// Closed event will fire. 
        /// </summary> 
        void Connection_Closed() 
        { 
            //Hide chat UI; show login UI 
            var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher; 
            dispatcher.Invoke(() => ChatPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed); 
            dispatcher.Invoke(() => ButtonSend.IsEnabled = false); 
            dispatcher.Invoke(() => StatusText.Content = "You have been disconnected."); 
            dispatcher.Invoke(() => SignInPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible); 
        } 

        private void SignInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            UserName = UserNameTextBox.Text; 
            //Connect to server (use async method to avoid blocking UI thread) 
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)) 
            {      
                StatusText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
                StatusText.Content = "Connecting to server..."; 
                ConnectAsync(); 
            } 
        } 

        private void WPFClient_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (Connection != null) 
            { 
                Connection.Stop(); 
                Connection.Dispose(); 
            } 
        }   
    } 
}
```

Check this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b/sourcecode?fileId=119892&pathId=422099136) for further reference.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohit, but my question is azure signalr app which use azure function for messaging